# How to compare SQL Query XML Varchar(max)?

Tags: sql, xml, varcharmax

How can I use less than or equal to comparison in this xml `varchar(max)` element?

```
select * 
from table 
where SHARED_XML.value('(//ns:Element[@ns:ElementId="29581"]/ns:ElementValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') < '10'
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: There are many unknowns  in your query: (1) namespace, (2) string comparison could be equal or not equal.